# Is there a way to reduce the Bandwidth taken By WCF?

Tags: wcf

I am newbie in WCF; I am developing a client server application and my goal is to execute some logic on the server side every one second.

I made small client to my WCF service using NetTcpBinding because it is the most optimized way in terms of BW (I understand) as it uses binary encoding?

After short tracing using [TracePlus](http://www.sstinc.com/ethernet.html) I found that when I call single function that does not take any parameter and return int value the size of the data sent from client to server is 400 byte!!

Is there a way to reduce this size? and if no this means I have to develop my application using native sockets? (the BW is critical issue in my case)

PS

Is 400 byte is acceptable size for calling method without arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can always author your own WCF transport/binding.  Have you 'turned off' all the unneeded features on NetTcpBinding (e.g. security) when measuring the 400 bytes?

Comment: I do not know what are the unneeded features, can you tell please?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx
probably security mode="None", reliableSession enabled="false", transactionFlow=false

Comment: Actually this does not help and will not solve the problem as I am using the default settings

Comment: I don't understand your comment; I think security is enabled by default, and I presume you don't need that (since you are considering 'rewrite at the socket layer').  So turn off security and see what it buys you.

Comment: the size of the packets down to 65 byte in the sending and 70 when receiving so the total method call takes 135 byte